# Android: dynamic resource values from layout xml

Tags: android, layout, resources

I have an application, in which I need to use diffrent text strings in each view.
I have already a function which returns the correct string according to internal state:

```
getText(String id)
```

so **getText("menuTitle")** might return **"Title1"** at one time, and **"Title2"** at another
and **getText("buttonX")** might return **"Press"** at one time, and **"Click"** at another

I have no problem to do this progmatically in each activity
however, as I have a lot of activities, it would be great if I can somehow override the resource mechanism, so instead of writing code in each Activity for each text

```
View v=findViewbyId(...);  
v.setText(setText(stringID));
```

I could set in the XML

```
....
<TextView text="myDir/menuTitle" />
```

and recieve a callback with the resource name so I could return

```
getText("menuTitle")
```

instead of reading the resource from the file

Comment: I do not see any advantage of your requirements. I just see an increased use of cpu.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one common Baseactivity which contains your common view and just extend this baseactivity in each of your activity class and just set the text over their.

Comment: there is no common view. I need to go through about 100 views in the application, and set it by code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need a binding mechanism. Take a look at [this young project](http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/). Or have some fun googling 'android binding' term.